# MVC bootstrap dropdownlistfor writable

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I am doing an MVC5 Bootstrap Application. I have a common `dropdownlistfor`
like this

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.user.Country_id, Model.AvailableCountries, new { @class = " Required ", @onclick = "hide();", @id = "Country_id" })
```

I have a Controller Method called `AvailableCountries` that brings all countries.

What I need is the ability to write a country in case it is not in the list.

I know there is a  `bootstrap-select.js` but I do not find an example how to use it and I do not if there is another way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Not related, but including `new { @id = "Country_id" }` is a bit pointless - it already has that `id` attribute

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to do this would probably be to add an "Other" option to the bottom of your Country list. Then they select "Other" have another freeform textbox appear using JQuery so they can write their country in.

Then in your post controller you just need to have some logic that takes the value from the extra textbox when "Other" was selected